# Is there a way to generate static html pages with Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, documentation-generation, asp.net-web-api-helppages

Currently, thanks to [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/creating-api-help-pages#adding-help-pages-to-an-existing-project), I'm able to see API help page.

But I need to run (or publish and deploy to IIS) that ASP.NET Web application.

Does `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage` provide any functionality to generate static API help html pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not perfect solution, but using wget I was able to go through all help pages and save them all.

Example:

```sh
$ wget -r -k -E http://<ip_address>/Help/
$ tree
.
└── <ip_address>
    ├── Areas
    │   └── HelpPage
    │       └── HelpPage.css
    ├── Help
    │   ├── Api
    │   │   ├── DELETE-api-delivery-Data0-is
    │   │   ├── DELETE-api-master-Data1-id
    │   │   ├── DELETE-api-master-Data2-id
    │   │   ├── DELETE-api-master-Data3-id
    │   │   ├── DELETE-api-master-Data4-id
    │   │   ├── DELETE-api-master-Data5-id
    │   │   ├── GET-api-OtherApi1
    │   │   ├── GET-api-OtherApi2
    │   │   ├── GET-api-OtherApi3
    │   │   └── GET-api-OtherApi4
    │   ├── index.html
    │   ├── ResourceModel@modelName=Data1
    │   ├── ResourceModel@modelName=Data2
    │   ├── ResourceModel@modelName=Data3
    │   ├── ResourceModel@modelName=Data4
    │   └── ResourceModel@modelName=Data5
    └── Help.1
```

Comment: How about the option: `  -k,  --convert-links             make links in downloaded HTML or CSS point to local files`

Comment: Thanks [albert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1657886/albert), it helped! I updated answer.